# Plot Multiple sensor data(Pandas, Matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I would like to firstly group my dataframe by "id" then by "Datetime". Then plot each sensor "temperature" data against "Datetime". Thanks!

Sudo code :

```
   _, ax = plt.subplots()
    df_ = plots.groupby(['moteid', "Datetime"])
    for sensorID in df_moteid.unique():
      plot df['temp'] against df['Datetime']
```

My data looks like this :
[image]

EDIT:
I managed to plot each senosor data by firstly declare `index_col='Datetime'` in read_csv, to make it primary index, then plot like this:

```
_, ax = plt.subplots()
for key, group in df.groupby('moteid'):
    rgb = np.random.rand(3,)
    group.plot.line(ax=ax, y='temp', color=[rgb], label=key)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your exact Problem? The sorting or the plotting. For plotting two lists there should be enough documentation on the internet (https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html). The same for sorting two lists (zip) . Thanks!

Comment: Do not include your data as picture. You should copy and paste the data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to display the evolution of the temperature of each sensor depending on datetime. Each sensor will have a different color depending on his id. I took the example of 4 sensors id :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors_moteid = {'1':'red', '2':'blue', '3':'green', '4':'black'}

_, ax = plt.subplots()
for key,group in df_.groupby('moteid'):
    group.plot.scatter(ax=ax, x='Datetime', y='temp', label=key, color = colors_moteid[str(key)])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks i am trying to investigate why the dots are not connected? By this i mean the each sensors data point is stand alone not connected.

Comment: You can use this to connect points : df_.groupby(['Datetime', 'moteid'])['temp'].mean().unstack().plot()

Comment: The plot is there, but still the values are segmented and the points are not connected.